# Parsing a difficult MongoDB field (with multi-level array)

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pentaho

**Hello Experts**,

I am trying to parse a MongoDB collection row, and after using `$unwind`,
one of the remaining fields looks like that:

```
[
    {
        "account_id": "1234",
        "cities": {
            "cityname1": {
                "param1": 1,
                "param2": 2
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "account_id": "2345",
        "cities": {
            "cityname2": {
                "param1": 3,
                "param2": 3
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "account_id": "3456",
        "cities": {
            "cityname3": {
                "param1": 8,
                "param2": 6
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Now, I would like to continue parsing this field, so I can extract the fieldname/value for `account_id`, for `param1` and for `param2`, hoping then to sum up the `param1` and `param2` values.
However, when I try to use a second `$unwind`, I receive those fields with "null" value.

How should I parse this field correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by "parse"?

Comment: I mean extracting successfully the values of each field, and then using them for aggregation (such as summing up)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$set` change cities into array by using `$objectToArray`
- `$unwind` unwind cities array
- `$group` group by account_id and cityname then sum up param1 and param2
  (you can only group by account_id or cityname, just remove one of them)

aggregate

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      cities: {
        "$objectToArray": "$cities"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$cities"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        account_id: "$account_id",
        "cityname": "$cities.k"
      },
      "sumOfParam1": {
        "$sum": "$cities.v.param1"
      },
      "sumOfParam2": {
        "$sum": "$cities.v.param2"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Dk6YvyLatk-)

Comment: Pro: using "set" to arrayify the data to unwind it afterwards = a good idea, also mongoplayground is something that is going to help me a lot.

Con: summary doesn't work for some reason, I probably need to fiddle with it a little.

If no better answers in 24h, I'll choose this answer as most helpful